# How does dataframe store large amount of data in memory and manipulate?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chunking

Suppose I have a large amount of data that I am loading into a dataframe by chunks;?
For eg : I have a table which is more than 40 Gb and selecting 3 columns may be around 2 - 3 gb suppose and records are 10 million (count of rows)

```
c = pd.read_sql("select a,b,c from table;", con=db, chunksize=10**2):
b = c['a']
```

Since It is reading the table chunk by chunk does it mean it is not loading the whole 3 gb in memory at once and operate only on 10^2 mb at once then goto next chunk automatically??

If not, how to make it behave like this?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the documentation

```
chunksize : int, default None
    If specified, return an iterator where chunksize is the number of rows
    to include in each chunk.
```

So first of all, chunksize denotes the number of rows and not the size in mb. Providing a chunksize also has the effect, that an iterator is returned instead of a dataframe. So you need to loop over that. Given that, on the python side you only need memory for the 10^2 rows.

Comment: Ah so, chunksize gives the row count. when you are saying loop over that, we just need a for loop like : for c in pd.read_sql("select a,b,c from table;", con=db, chunksize=10**2):

Comment: That would be a way to do it. `iter = pd.read_sql("select a,b,c from table;", con=db, chunksize=10**2)` and `for df in iter:` would be equivalent.